# Exception thrown: read access violation. pn was 0x2. When Using GTK in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, gtk, visual-studio-2019

I want to build an app in C (for Windows) With GUI using GTK+ (on visual studio).
I have installed GTK, but when I use example codes from google - when I try to press a button in the app
or on any place in the app - I get an error in the file "ffi.c" (which isn't part of my code - it's a part of GTK library)...

The code is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget* win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget* btn = gtk_button_new_with_label("Close window");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), btn);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

And The Error is:
["Exception thrown: read access violation. pn was 0x2.". --> press this link to see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpdak.png)

And the Gtk window is:
[Press the link to see a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATozr.png)

I'm using Windows 10, and Visual Studio 2019 (With GTK+ 3)
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have managed to fix it if I use in VS the Release Mode instead of the Debug Mode (Someone knows why it happens only in Debug and not in release?)

Comment: Why you declare main as VOID?

Comment: By the way, I am strongly suggest you [that you are using GTK3](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVopEfWiFX88_zUzk08ZdrIc) and not GTK2. [Here you have everything you need to start working with GTK3](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeZXCNsTodx0EPcAfc6s0Ew)

Comment: I'm using VOID because it's just a test... but the problem isn't with that but with the GTK, I have managed to fix - It starts to work if I change in VS from Debug mode to Release mode... But I want to use the debugging mode... I want to upgrade to GTK3 but I don't know how to delete the current version...

Comment: @tomervainer, The *only* strictly-conforming return type for a C program's `main()` function is `int`.  Implementations may allow other return types as an extension, but I see no reason here to exercise any such extension that MS might provide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, but it's not the problem.. it was just a test... The problem is in another file (ffi.c)...

Comment: @tomervainer, if you think that your program exhibiting undefined behavior is not a problem, then perhaps you should be considering a different course of study.  If you think you can reliably predict how UB will or won't  manifest, then I suggest reviewing the definition of "undefined".  And if you are confident that you know the the locus of the problem you're interested in, then why are you asking here? In any event, I urge you to cultivate good programming habits, even where you think you can get away with sloppiness -- even where you *know* that you could get away with sloppiness, in fact.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You didn't understood me...  I know I shouldn't use the Void, it's not my code, it's just a test code from google *copy-paste*, and it's a code that should work, but there is a strange problem (that there is an error in the GTK library files, that occurs only in debug mode but not in release mode) This code should work because it's not mine - it's an example code from a site - that should work (because it works for other people), and the problem most likely not in the code but in visual studio.
I have tried with int main() and return 0, and it didn't work there too...

Comment: In that case, @tomervainer, the correct answer to Michi's question would have been "I'm using VOID because because I copy/pasted someone else's code without modification, and that's what they used."  Although I am inclined to agree that this misuse is not likely to be responsible for the misbehavior you observe, I am mystified as to why you are defending it.  It's not even your code.  And inasmuch as it produces undefined behavior (of the entire program), it is not out of the question that it could cause the program to fail for you under some circumstances, but not others.